# Assigning stm topic model & LDA models to original dataset and renaming topic names

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

I'm using the powerful Quanteda library and I wonder which is the best way to assign a topic model created using a STM model. In other words, once I have found my n topics using the `stm` fun over a `dfm` object, how do I create a data frame with each docid and its corresponding topic?

Let's say I have the following example:

```
 dfm_to_model <- tokens(head(data_corpus_inaugural, 50),
              remove_punct = TRUE) %>% 
              tokens_remove(stopwords("en")) %>% 
              dfm() %>% 
              dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 0.3, termfreq_type = "quantile", 
              min_docfreq = 0.05, docfreq_type = "prop")


stm_topic = stm(dfm_to_model, K = 5, max.em.its = 150, control=list(alpha=1))
stm_topic


plot(stm_topic, type="summary")
```

Image:

[image]

Now let's make a LDA example:

```
tmod_lda <- textmodel_lda(dfm_to_model, k = 5) # LDA MODEL

> seededlda::terms(tmod_lda, 10)
      topic1         topic2   topic3      topic4       topic5   
 [1,] "government"   "us"     "great"     "government" "must"   
 [2,] "constitution" "let"    "every"     "upon"       "world"  
 [3,] "union"        "people" "country"   "people"     "can"    
 [4,] "power"        "world"  "public"    "laws"       "nations"
 [5,] "states"       "time"   "united"    "must"       "justice"
 [6,] "people"       "now"    "states"    "shall"      "life"   
 [7,] "can"          "new"    "citizens"  "congress"   "peace"  
 [8,] "upon"         "one"    "may"       "can"        "men"    
 [9,] "one"          "shall"  "war"       "law"        "nation" 
[10,] "may"          "can"    "interests" "american"   "upon"   
>
```

But how do I know which topic belongs to which `document id`? Also, is there a way to rename the labels of the topics such as topic 1: "Leadership" for both the stm and the LDA model?

Comment: You mean something like `docvars(dfm_to_model, "lda_topics") <- topics(tmod_lda)`?

Comment: Hi Phiver thanks for your reply, yes I want to create a dataframe where I can see a column where I have the doc_id and what topic it belongs to, also notice that some doc are empy so I'm guessing there is no topic assing to them right? Im assuming that those docs will have NA as topic thank you so much

Comment: Yes, `seededlda::topics()` returns NA for empty documents. You can label topics through a keyword dictionary using `textmodel_seededlda()`.